# How to use mouse over on over indentation menus

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**This is the flow i wanna automate (MARKED IN BOLD) ==>> I'm very new to selenium**

**File**

**New** **-->** **Project** **-->** **Java**

```
                C#

                Perl

                Python
```

Consider only mouseover alone available in the menu elements, other then the last option **(JAVA)** which have click functionality

Script I:

```
            // MouseHover       
    WebElement menu = wd.findElement(By.linkText("Setup School"));

    WebElement submenu = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Edit')])[3]"));

    WebElement sidemenu = wd.findElement(By.linkText("Register School"));


    // Action
    Actions action = new Actions(wd);

    // Hover action     

    action.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);;

    action.moveToElement(submenu).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);;

    action.moveToElement(sidemenu).perform();
    action.click(sidemenu).build().perform();
```

Script II:

```
            action.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();;
    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    action.moveToElement(submenu).build().perform();;
    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        action.moveToElement(wd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Register School')]"))).click().build().perform();
```

I have tried all the options even Xpath contains(text, href), css and linktext but nothing is working.

Initially it mouseovers the first element (File) but it stucked in future process..!

```
            WebElement submenu = wd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/ul/li[3]/a"));
            WebElement submenu = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Edit')])[3]"));
```

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //a[contains(text(),'Edit')])[3] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. 
The following error occurred:

InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[contains(text(),'Edit')])[3] because of the following error:
[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: ""]
Command duration or timeout: 8 milliseconds

For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=29.0.1, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: The given selector //a[contains(text(),'Edit')])[3] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.

The following error occurred:

InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[contains(text(),'Edit')])[3] because of the following error:
[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: ""]

**This is what im getting when ever changing the xpath(), css(), linktext().**

Please help me out for resolving this.!

Comment: Essentially the exception is telling you that you haven't given a legal XPath expression. See @Santoshsarma's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below locator.

```
By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Edit')])[3]")
```

Comment: I have already used this xpath, it also not working.
 WebElement submenu = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Edit')])[3]")); (Also mentioned it in the question by using this Xpath)

Comment: In that xpath (which you've used) there is error. that is why it is throwing not a legal expression. Try with the xpath that I've mentioned in answer.

Comment: Its working but throwing another errors 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"txtname"}
Command duration or timeout: 21 milliseconds

I have tried Thread.sleep(2000) also driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Is above locator working as expected ? Based on your comment problem is with some other locator. NoSuchElementException (id='txtname') . Have you verified in firebug? Is that element in iframe?

Comment: Yes i have verified with fire bug the element is present in it..!

<input id="txtname" class="textbox" type="text" style="width:300px;" tabindex="1" maxlength="100" name="txtschoolname">

Comment: Can you add the html snippet with required screen shots of your problematic part?

Comment: <table id="Table2" class="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0"><tbody>
<tr>
<td class="head" colspan="4">
</tr>
<tr align="left">
<td align="left" style="width: 0%"> </td>
<td align="left" style="width: 15%">  </td>
<td align="left" style="width: 42%"> </td>
<td align="left" style="width: 43%"> </td>
</tr>
<tr align="left">
<td> </td>
<td>
<span id="lblschoolname" class="label">School Name *</span>
</td>
<td>
<input id="txtname" class="textbox" type="text" style="width:300px;" tabindex="1" maxlength="100" name="txtschoolname">

Comment: Hey thanks man, i figured it out by myself, All i need to do is switch over to the frame first then to the elements..!

Comment: You are welcome !! Thats what I've asked you in my previous comments. Whether is that in iframe?